# AngularJS osm leaflet - access denied to tiles

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome, leaflet, openstreetmap

I use osm in my AngularJS app and in Google Chrome browser I get the following messages

[image: Access denied to tiles]

So I do not have access (any more) to the tiles. Three days ago it worked fine. If I open the application in Firefox everything is fine and works.
Is this an adjustment in Google Chrome or how I can find out what I have to do in order to get it work with Google Chrome anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not adhering to the tile usage policy. That's why your access denied message links to that policy.

OSM became stricter in enforcing the policy recently.

Could be related to another provider that slashed It's free tier by 99% recently and therefore users flocking to OSM.

As the tile usage policy stats: "OpenStreetMap data is free for everyone to use. Our tile servers are not."

(see: https://operations.osmfoundation.org/policies/tiles/ )

So please follow that policy closely if you use OSM for light use. For use in a business context or an app you shouldn't use those tile servers by the OSMF anyway (see the usage policy that asks you not to hardcode the tile.openstreetmap.org URL into an app).
Alternatives can be found here: https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tile_servers

If your angular application is producing only light use and not used for business contexts, check your dev tools in Chrome about the User-Agent and referrer your angular app is sending.

Comment: I don't think that is the problem. `If I open the application in Firefox everything is fine and works.`

Comment: That's why I recommend to check the Headers in Chrome dev tools and compare to Firefox. OSM is starting to block more and more applications and they started with typical Android headers and Chrome headers but will move on to iOS and FF headers as well. They block by headers, user-agents and referrers. So you'll have to find the difference between those in Chrome and in Firefox. Either Chrome is missing sth. or you may see blocking coming to Firefox as well for this Angular app in the future. Or some malicious app is faking your Chrome headers and that header got blocked, but not the FF one.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this will help, but from PINTOSTACK, in

https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/83887/unable-to-download-tiles-403-forbidden

"Maybe this will help someone else, for those using leaflet, we fixed it by changing http to https on the tileLayer png. Seems to work on localhost in Chrome & Edge."

I made the change and this worked for me.

Comment: I had same issue